# Let me View Markdown of a question/answer

Tags: feature-request, support

As I do not have enough reputation I can not edit questions and answers.  However I sometime wish to **view** the Markdown so I can see how someone has done some formatting etc.

So there is a hard (hack) way of doing this, should there be a direct link.  E.g. "view marked" link instead of an "edit link" when no edit rights?

Comment: Should have realised you only have a zero case of interest in answers.

Comment: random, most meta questions don't have ONE best answer unlike stackoverflow.

Comment: If TheTXI or Welbog post an answer in Meta, that's the best answer by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grab the post ID of the question in question. It's between the **`question`** and the SEO friendy part of the URL. Just grab the first set of numbers you see really. And then put it in the **XXX** of the sample URL below:

> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/**XXX**/list

So for this, while you may not have yet edited it, [you can still see the revisions list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/21326/list) if you follow the above template. Then click the **View source** link of the relevant edit edition.

If you want to play around with how a post will look, [spend some time in the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sandbox link; I hadn't seen that yet.

Comment: But you have a diamond next to your name. You all are suppose to see *everything*.

Comment: It would be practical to have a "view markdown" button.

Comment: This is as good a workaround there can be. But yes, a `view markdown` would be highly preferable.